# Django admin does update instead of insert

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My models are the following:

```
class Station(models.Model):
     sid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     uid = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='uid', verbose_name='User')
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     # and others...     
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Stations'

class Playlist(models.Model):
    plid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    changed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Playlists'

class Stationplaylist(models.Model):
     spid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='spid')
     sid = models.ForeignKey(Station, db_column='sid')
     plid = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, db_column='plid')
     syncronized = models.BooleanField()
     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.plid.name
     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'StationsPlaylists'
         unique_together=('sid', 'plid')
```

and I want to perform insert operation in my view:

```
def addPlaylist(request, app_label='webadmin', **kwargs):
    # stuff...
    selected_playlists = request.POST.getlist('selected_playlists[]')
    current_station = request.POST.get('station')
    totalPlaylists = Stationplaylist.objects.filter(sid=current_station).count()
    last_spid = None        
    for playlist in selected_playlists:
        if playlist != 'on':
            if totalPlaylists==0:
                last_spid=1
            elif last_spid == None:
                last_obj = Stationplaylist.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
                last_spid = last_obj.spid + 1
            else:
                last_spid += 1
            Stationplaylist(last_spid, current_station, playlist, 0).save() # 0-syncronized
            totalPlaylists+=1
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

but when I call this for, say Station#1, with 3 playlists and then I call this on another one, let it be Station#2, the playlists are simply updated. I mean, in database, their station field is updated to the Station#2.

Why is that happening and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've overridden the automatic primary key and made it a pure IntegerField. This doesn't autoincrement, so every new instance gets the same default primary key.

You really shouldn't define your own primary key field unless you have a really good reason. But if you do have that good reason, you should use [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#autofield) rather than IntegerField.

Comment: I'm using the last_spid to simulate auto_increment.
Thanks for the link.

Comment: Yuck, I just noticed that code. Please don't do this: you're subject to all sorts of horrible race conditions.

Comment: Ok, I changed that field to AutoField and when I do
   p = Playlistsong(current_playlist, song, totalSongs+1)
   p.save()
server returns 'internal error'.
What would cause that?

Comment: You probably need to migrate your database to create the new autoincrement field.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a database problem..when I run the same from shell, it works fine

Comment: I use an existing mysql database, that is why I need my own primary key. Those models where auto-generated using inspectdb. There were some modifications introduced in that DB table, could those be the problem?

Comment: My code was a total mess, the problem was there. Anyway, I'll accept your answer as a dos vs. don't dos. Thanks for your time.